# Activate an on-click and on mousedown event in a Firefox extension in Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, mouseevent

I have code that is in a content script that is injected by a page mod. This runs on a timer and checks that the 'send' button of a compose window in Gmail is open, and if it is then I want it to add these two properties of mousedown and click.

The end goal is to capture the information in the email to perform tracking operations on it, but for now I just want the print statements to print when the events are triggered.

Sendelem refers to the 'send' button, and as of the current code, neither is activated when the button is clicked or when mousedown is activated.

This is the code that I have for mousedown:

```
//when the send button is pushed
sendelem.on("mousedown", function() {
    var send = $(this).data('sent');
    console.log("mouse pressed down");
    ....
});
```

And the same for onclick, just replacing "mousedown" with "onclick".
I also tried writing it like this:

```
//when the send button is pushed
sendelem.mousedown(function() {
      var send = $(this).data('sent');
      console.log("mouse pressed down");
      ...
 });
```

and

```
//when the send button is pushed
$(sendelem).mousedown(function() {
      var send = $(this).data('sent');
      console.log("mouse pressed down");
      ...
 });
```

Comment: You do not state what the problem is, only that this is the code you are using. Please also show how the code is being used. What type of ad-on is this (SDK, restartless, overlay)? Is it being used in a content script? Where is `sendelem` defined/assigned? Please [edit] the question to include more information and ask an actual question/pose a problem.

Comment: This question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. Your question is unclear, debugging is assumed.